# access() return no writable right when the limits.conf file with 644 right

Tags: python, linux

The right of /etc/security/limits.conf is 644

When i use python:
>>import os;
>>os.access("/etc/security/limits.conf", os.W_OK);
False

The linux has disable the SELinux, i am confusion now.

[image]

And, when i vi this file, there is "[readonly]" at the bottom, others file with the same rights(644), there is not this prompt.
So i guess is certain security system keep this file readonly even with 644, it is bad i don't get it.

Comment: You're probably not the owner of this file. The permission 4 to other users and group means "read only", so the result is correct: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chmod#Octal_modes

Comment: I use root user to login the system, and execute the above commands.   And the file(/etc/security/limits.conf)'s owner and group is root:root

Comment: I add one screenshot, and os.R_OK return True

Answer (score 0):

`os.access` doesn't throw error if the input file do not exist. Just to make sure the python can see the file, can you run `os.access` with `F_OK` flag?

UPDATE:

You already said R_OK returns true, so I doubt `F_OK` flag is going to highlight any useful information, but it is still worth giving it a try.

e.g.

```
>>> os.access(r'/etc/xpasswd', os.F_OK)
False
>>>
```

vs

```
>>> os.access(r'/etc/passwd', os.F_OK)
True
>>>
```

Also, try some of the below commands to see if they highlight any issue.

As root:

```
>>> import os
>>> os.getuid()
0
>>> os.access(r'/etc/passwd', os.R_OK)
True
>>> os.access(r'/etc/passwd', os.W_OK)
True
>>> os.access(r'/etc/passwd', os.F_OK)
True
>>> os.access(r'/etc/xpasswd', os.R_OK)
False
>>> os.access(r'/etc/xpasswd', os.W_OK)
False
>>> os.stat(r'/etc/xpasswd')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/etc/xpasswd'
>>>
```

As non-root:

```
>>> import os
>>> os.getuid()
501
>>> os.access(r'/etc/passwd', os.R_OK)
True
>>> os.access(r'/etc/passwd', os.W_OK)
False
>>> os.access(r'/etc/passwd', os.F_OK)
True
>>> os.access(r'/etc/xpasswd', os.R_OK)
False
>>>
```

Comment: I used os.stat() method to test the file, with result:posix.stat_result(st_mode=33188, st_ino=1573096, st_dev=51713L, st_nlink=1, st_uid=0, st_gid=0, st_size=1868, st_atime=xxxxxxxxx, st_mtime=xxxxx, st_ctime=xxxxxxx). I guess the issue is caused by security, but i cannot find it.